# Show some menu sub items as dropdown under a menu item

Tags: functions, menus, theme-options

I have made a custom wordpress menu -

```
function my_custom_menu_item($items, $args)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary')
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; 
        $items .= '<li><a href="">'.$name.'</a></li>';

        $items .= '<li><a href="/my-profile">My Profile</a></li>';
        $items .= '<li><a href="/my-posts">My Posts</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);
```

It shows 'name of the logged in user', 'My Profile', 'My Posts' side by side in a flat structutre.

I want 'My Profile' and 'My Posts' to show as dropdown under 'name of the logged in user'. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first closing `</li>` and wrap the sub-items inside `<ul></ul>`, then close the parent `<li>`.

For Example:

```
function my_custom_menu_item($items, $args)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary')
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; 
        $items .= '<li><a href="">'.$name.'</a>';
        $items .= '<ul>';
        $items .= '<li><a href="/my-profile">My Profile</a></li>';
        $items .= '<li><a href="/my-posts">My Posts</a></li>';
        $items .= '<ul>';
        $items .= '</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);
```